# Listar impressoras do print server instaladas de uma estação remota

Tags: cmd, shell-script, shell, powershell, vbscript

Trabalho em uma empresa que possui a seguinte estrutura:

Cada cidade do meu estado possui uma sede com um servidor que também é print server, nele estão as impressoras desta sede.

Utilizo para realizar a instalação das impressoras o psexec do Systernals em conjunto com um comando para realizar a sua instalação, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
psexec \\172.20.19.218 cmd /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n\\SRV-1112\PRT-2181
psexec \\172.20.19.218 cmd /c start /wait sc stop spooler
psexec \\172.20.19.218 cmd /c start /wait sc start spooler
```

Contudo muitas vezes, antes de realizar a instalação, gostaria de saber se a impressora já está instalada na estação do usuário, sem precisar entrar em contato com o mesmo e acessar remotamente via vnc. Mas os comandos que possuo nunca mostram essas impressoras, apenas as impressoras virtuais do Windows e de outros programas, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
PS C:\Users\paulogoncalves> wmic /node:172.20.19.218 printer list status
Name                           Status
TASKalfa 3050ci                Degraded
Send To OneNote 2016
PDFCreator                     Unknown
Microsoft XPS Document Writer  Unknown
Microsoft Print to PDF         Unknown
Fax                            Unknown
doPDF 8                        Unknown
```

Notem que a impressora \\SRV-1112\PRT-2181 não está listada. Agora, se realizo essa consulta em minha estação local, as impressoras aparecem:

```
PS C:\Users\paulogoncalves> wmic printer list status
Name                           Status
Send To OneNote 2016           Unknown
PDFCreator                     Unknown
Microsoft XPS Document Writer  Unknown
Microsoft Print to PDF         Unknown
Fax                            Unknown
doPDF 8                        Unknown
\\srv-1378\PRT-1000            Unknown
\\srv-1419\PRT-1061            Unknown
\\172.20.16.40\PRT-2181        Unknown
```

A pergunta é: Existe algum comando que realize a listagem, inclusive, das impressoras remotas (esse pode ser em powershell, vbscript ou bat) ou isso é um bloqueio de rede que impede a visualização?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, o que você realiza é o mapeamento de uma impressora de rede no perfil do usuário. Isto não é bem uma instalação. Chamamos isso de capturar a fila da impressora disponibilizada em servidor.

O que você deseja é saber quais as filas de impressora existem para um usuário determinado, provavelmente o usuário que está em sessão na estação.

Não acredito que seja bloqueio na rede. O comando "WMIC", e acredito que outros comandos, apenas retornarão as impressoras no contexto da máquina, e não de um usuário específico.

Uma possível solução seria abrir remotamente um caminho específico do registro de usuários.

```
$Credencial = Get-Credential
New-PSSession -Credential $Credencial -ComputerName $ComputadorRemoto |
    Enter-PSSession
$Resultado = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Registry::\HKey_Users\*\Printers\Connections' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
#   Tratar $Resultado
Exit
```